# $f(n)=f(n-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor) + n$ Prove that f(n) is less than or equal to $3n\sqrt n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

[image]

In the question above, I need help with part B

I tried many things like induction, showing the limit of the ratio goes to $0$, Defining $g(n)=f(n)-3n\sqrt n$ and proceeding with showing it will become negative. Finally kept trying to find patterns. I got that $f(n)-n=f(n-k)$ where $k$ is the position of the square number closest to $n$ in the set $\{1,4,9,16,\ldots\}$

I have a feeling none of these is working so what is a proper way to solve this and also please teach me how to approach similar problems like these in the future.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: At least the rate of the convergence is trivial. Note that each iteration is $a_{n} = a_{n-1} - \sqrt{a_{n-1}}$. You can upper bound it, based on the fact that each square root is no greater than $\sqrt{n}$. Hence, there are no more than $C n / \sqrt{n}$ iterations, and each iteration greatest term is $n$.

Comment: @openspace what is $a_n$ here

Comment: You can define $a_n = n$ and calculate till the $a_1$. Or the same way $a_0 = n$, $a_{i+1} = a_{i} - \sqrt{a_i}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use $n_0 = 1$, and prove

$$f(n) \le 3n\sqrt{n} = g(n) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

is true for all $n \ge n_0$ using [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction). The base case of $n = 1$ has $1 = f(1) \le 3(1)(\sqrt{1})$. Assume, for some $k \ge 1$, that \eqref{eq1A} is true for all $1 \le n \le k$. With $n = k + 1$, for some positive integer $m$, then

$$m = \lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor \;\;\to\;\; n = m^2 + j, \;\; 0 \le j \le 2m \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

From the definition of $f(n)$, and the induction hypothesis, we then get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(n) & = f\left((m^2 + j) - m\right) + m^2 + j \\
& \le 3(m^2 + j - m)\sqrt{m^2 + j - m} + (m^2 + j)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Next, consider

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
h(n) & = g(n) - \left(3(m^2 + j - m)\sqrt{m^2 + j - m} + (m^2 + j)\right) \\
& = 3(m^2 + j)\sqrt{m^2 + j} - \left((m^2 + j) + 3(m^2 + j - m)\sqrt{m^2 + j - m}\right) \\
& = (m^2+j)\left(3\sqrt{m^2 + j} - 1\right) - 3(m^2 + j - m)\sqrt{m^2 + j - m}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Unfortunately, using just $\sqrt{m^2+j} \ge m$ and $\sqrt{m^2 - j + m} \lt m + \frac{1}{2}$ doesn't result in $h(n) \ge 0$. Instead, splitting the handling of the range of $j$ into $2$ parts allows the use of more accurate inequalities. First, with $0 \le j \le m$, we have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& m^2 + j \ge m^2 \;\to\; \sqrt{m^2 + j} \ge m \\
& m^2 + j - m \le m^2 \;\to\; \sqrt{m^2 + j - m} \le m
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Using this in \eqref{eq4A} gives that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
h(n) & \ge (m^2+j)(3m - 1) - 3(m^2 + j - m)(m) \\
& = (m^2+j)(3m - 1) - 3m(m^2+j) + 3m^2 \\
& = -(m^2 + j) + 3m^2 \\
& = 2m^2 - j \\
& \gt 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Second, with $m+1 \le j \le 2m$, we then get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& m^2 + j \gt m^2 + m + \frac{1}{4} \;\to\; \sqrt{m^2 + j} \gt m + \frac{1}{2} \\
& m^2 + j - m \lt m^2 + m + \frac{1}{4} \;\to\; \sqrt{m^2 + j - m} \lt m + \frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Using this in \eqref{eq4A} results in

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
h(n) & \gt (m^2+j)\left(3\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right) - 1\right) - 3(m^2 + j - m)\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& = (m^2+j)\left(3m + \frac{1}{2}\right) - (m^2 + j)\left(3m+\frac{3}{2}\right) + 3m\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& = -(m^2 + j) + 3m^2 + \frac{3m}{2} \\
& = 2m^2 + \frac{3m}{2} - j \\
& \gt 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Thus, \eqref{eq6A} and \eqref{eq8A} together show that $h(n) \gt 0$ so, from \eqref{eq4A} and \eqref{eq3A}, we get \eqref{eq1A} is also true for $n = k + 1$ and, therefore, by strong induction, it's true for all $n \ge 1$.

---

Note tighter bounds for $f(n)$ also work, e.g., reducing $3$ to $2$ in \eqref{eq1A} to get $f(n)\le 2n\sqrt{n}$. Then \eqref{eq6A} results in $m^2 - j \ge 0$, and \eqref{eq8A} ends up as $m^2 + m - j \ge 0$.

Comment: Nice work ! $\rm {+1 }$.

Answer (score 0):

I found a general formular for $f(n)$
\begin{align*}
f(n)&=n(2x^2+2x+1-n)\\
&-\dfrac{x(x+1)(6x^2+2x+1)}{6}\\ &+\left\lfloor\frac{n-x^2}{x+1}\right\rfloor(2x+1)(n-x^2-x)\end{align*}
For all $n\ge1$, where: $x=\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$

[This sequence](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5Bn%282x%5E2%2B2x%2B1-n%29-x%28x%2B1%29%286x%5E2%2B2x%2B1%29%2F6%2Bfloor%28%28n-x%5E2%29%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%282x%2B1%29%28n-x%5E2-x%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C100%7D%5D%2C%20where%20x%3Dfloor%28sqrt%28n%29%29)

Comment: I personally think you should not be listing this as an answer if [you yourself are not sure it is the right closed form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820778/fn-fn-lfloor-sqrt-n-rfloorn), nor does this really make it clear how to establish the bound in question.